# creating stunts to improve the effect of declartions or manuvers?

Tags: dresden-files, stunts

I want a character that is focused more on non-combat skills, but in combat focuses on indirectly helping via maneuvers and/or declarations with little ability to do direct damage.

Since I want this to be his focus I'm looking to create stunts to focus on it.  Right now I'm wondering if it's possible to create a stunt that specifically boosts the affect of maneuvers/declarations when other's tag them.  My problem is that it's hard to think of stunts that feel balanced and flavorful that could modify a maneuver.

Part of my problem is that any stunt that can be utilized to enhance any maneuver for free feels too powerful, short of giving it an absurdly high refresh cost.  It's so flexible and going to be utilized for every round of combat that any increase to basic maneuvers I can think of feels like it may be too powerful.

One possible stunt I had thought of was allowing spending a fate point to offer a second free tag of an aspect a create, which is underwhelming since all it does is let me spend the fate point instead of a teammate for the second tag.  Perhaps a stunt could allow spending a fate point to allow 3 free tags of an aspect created but that feels odd, overpowered when 3 tags are used, but potentially wasted if combat ends too fast?

The other option I thought of was allowing the first free tag to get an extra +1, but I'm not sure what affect that would have on balance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the Dresden Files rules don't really cover this, Fate core has a few stunt ideas that may apply.  Specifically, they tend to be based around the once-per-scene limit.  "Once per scene, you may gain an additional free tag when creating an aspect by ____" type stuff.  E. G. "Watch your Step!  Once per scene, when creating a maneuver by using fire evocation to create a slippery terrain with ice, gain an additional free tag."  Negotiate with your DM the exact depth of specificity required for the stunt -- my DM let me get away with just a generic 'when using XYZ skill', yours may or may not accept something that broad.